# AChartEngine Android - reset zoom and pan of graph?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am building an Android Application and I am using AChartEngine to display a graph and values I obtain.

I am able to graph the values I have properly. However, once the user zooms in and pans around my graph, it becomes difficult to view the data. One option I considered is to display a "redraw graph" button where once the user clicks it, the graph would redraw itself to the original state, zoom and pan would also reset.

Here's by code thus far:

```
public void redrawGraph(View view){
    chartView.repaint();
}
```

where `redrawGraph` is a the `onClick` function of my button and `chartView` is an object of type `GraphicalView`.

However, that does seem to do anything as it only repaints changes in my graph (if I added/removed series renderers, series, etc).

How can I reset the zoom and pan of graphs in AChartEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer refers to XY/time charts. First you have to enable the external zoom feature in every renderer you use. The snippet below shows the code for accomplishing this:

```
yourMultipleSeriesRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
```

In your method `redrawGraph` you then have to execute the command shown below:

```
public void redrawGraph(View view) {
    chartView.zoomReset();
}
```

This works great for me. If you need any further information leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry I only got back to my question now (I actually googled my problem and this was the first result). I'll try this right now and get back to you.

Comment: Works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Put this in your Multiple Series Render

```
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    // setting pan enablity which uses graph to move on both axis
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    // setting click false on graph
    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
    // setting zoom to false on both axis
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
    // setting lines to display on y axis
    multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
    // setting lines to display on x axis
    multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
    // setting legend to fit the screen size
    multiRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    // setting displaying line on grid
    multiRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    // setting zoom to false
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    // setting external zoom functions to false
    multiRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This code disables zoom and pan along the Y-Axis. It does not reset the zoom level and pan position as I originally asked in my question.